# How to return routes to views in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, routes

I just tried loading a view using a route like so:

```
route.php
Route::get("/page", function(){
   return View::make("dir.page");
});


controller.php
View::make("/page");
```

...and an error was  thrown. So my question is:

Is it possible to load a route via a view and if its possible then how?

Thanks.

Comment: Passing the View as a closure in the `routes.php` should work, you just need to add `return View::make('dir.page');`

Doing so, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with controller.php, since it won't be called by the route.

Comment: Exactly my point. I didn't want to do a Redirect::to() call on the Route but a View::make() on it. Apparently that was me asking too much of Laravel. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

In Laravel 5.5 you can now do:

```
Route::view('/page', 'dir.page');
```

Answer (score 14):

Your should `return` your View.

So this will work fine:

```
Route::get("/page", function(){
   return View::make("dir.page");
});
```

Comment: @Cozzbie Sure it's causing an error. And obviously that error is View not found, cause you trying to pass Route's name to `View`, when you should pass a view name

Comment: View name or View path and if it's View name, how do you declare them? Thanks

Comment: @Cozzbie Yeah, sorry for this inaccuracy. I meant View path. Like if you have `/views/folder/template.php` you would do `return View::make('folder/template');`

Comment: @Cozzbie I recommend you to check Laravel's documentation. [link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2). It can answer almost any question you'll have at beginning.

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::view('RouteName', 'dir.filename'); // version 6+
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Laravel 7:

```
Route::get("/page", function(){
   return view("dir.page");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.8 I had to use this.

```
Route::get("/page", function(){
   return \View::make("dir.page");
});
```